# Error 40 - Could not a open connection to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my windows application there is an error. Please can anyone tell me what is my mistake in connection string for local database? This is my code:

```
<add name="ACT_WIN.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;
    Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And this is my error:

> [image: error message]

Comment: Is your sql server activated ?

Comment: We want to use Local DB

Comment: Okay, but you need to make sure that the server is activated. Check the sql server in your services.msc

Comment: It doesn't exist in target computer

Comment: I been install the SQL Server Express LocalDB  and it was started in services.msc but I have same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Wrong is in `app.config` -> `ConnectionString` -> `Data Source`=. or someting else,without set other Properties
try this in `ConnectionString`...

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;integrated security=true;database=DB" providerName="System.Data.SQLExpress"
```

Good Luck

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx